# og:title and og:description ignored in Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I'm trying to implement the 'Like' Facebook button on my webpage. I've followed the instructions on [FB Like Button Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), and the main functionalities seem to be working Ok.

However, there are a couple of things that I couldn't make them work: the **og:title** and **og:description** meta tags. It looks like they are simply ignored when I post to Facebook.

This is the list of key information that may be helpful:

1. My Facebook web page: [www.facebook.com/zuzsso](http://www.facebook.com/zuzsso), and I've configured it as follows:
   [image]
2. My webpage is [www.zuzsso.com](http://www.zuzsso.com)
3. The header source code of my webpage looks like this, where I've set the tags **og:title** and **og:description**
   [image]
4. The FB **scraper** shows this information when debugging the URL http://www.zuzsso.com:
   [image]
5. Also, this is how the **scraper** sees my page:
   [image]

**However**

When I log in Facebook as someone else and go to my webpage and like it, this is what I see:
[image]

Given all this info, shall I assume that I misunderstood how the Like button works or is it there definitely a problem with FB or my own configurations?

Thanks a lot for your time hand help.

N

Comment: I suspect people are liking your FB page and not your website itself...
Could you provide the code that implements your like button?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was pointing to my facebook webpage: <div class="fb-like" 
 data-href="http://www.facebook.com/zuzsso" 
 data-width="400" 
 data-colorscheme="dark" 
 data-show-faces="true" 
 data-send="true" 
data-layout="button_count">
However, if I do that way, I can't see who liked the page. Only the number of people who liked it

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/558614320852814/likes

Comment: But, that only works if those people are in your friends list! (Or have enabled public viewing of their profile.)

Comment: Yes, I know, this is why I've changed the URL to point to the FB page, where anyone would be shown in the time line, even if they aren't in the friend list. Anyway, it was very helpful and now I have a better understanding. Thanks so much.